# Select into an exisiting table using FoxPro

Tags: foxpro

Hi I am currently using FoxPro and may I know if there is any possible chance to select into exisiting table by overwritting it.

For example: I wanted to achieve this:
 SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE criteria INTO TABLE `table1`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. How about

```
use table1 excl
delete from table1 where !criteria
pack in table1
```

Comment: Thanks. I've never thought about that!

Comment: Mark it as answered then eh ;)

Comment: I have edited the code to make it safer and remove the possibility of deleting records from the wrong table.

Comment: Alright I will check it out.  I am not sure if it is applicable for FoxPro 7.0. Thanks!

Comment: Should be OK on VFP7